# Bootstrap 3 inline row within horizontal form

Tags: forms, twitter-bootstrap, inline

Really need some help gurus.  Have tried other answers and a lot of playing around.  I have a horizontal form and with this I'd like an inline row which has two check boxes the second one with a label and then an input box.

col labe1 chb1 chb2 chb2_lable input box

What i have at the moment is close but i don't have a label for the second checkbox however i try it is messes up the layout.  Please help!``

currently i have

```
    <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6" >
        <form class="form-horizontal" role="form" >
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="price" class="col-sm-4 control-label">Order</label>
                <div class="col-xs-6">
                    <div class="form-inline">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox-inline" name="tip" id="tip" ng-model="isLimit" ng-change="isLimitChanged()" title="Only buy if price is on or below limit, or sell if price is on or above limit">
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group" >
                            <div class="col-sm-4 form-inline">
                                <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox-inline" name="deduct" >
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group" >
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="price" 
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
</form>
</div>
</div>
```

Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try Using this :)

```
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-6" >
<form class="form-horizontal" role="form" >
   <div class="form-group">
   <label for="price" class="col-sm-4 control-label">Order</label>
   <div class="col-xs-6">
      <div class="form-inline">
         <div class="form-group">
            <label class="checkbox">
            <input type="checkbox"> Check me out
            </label>
         </div>
         <div class="form-group" >
            <div class="col-sm-4 form-inline">
               <label class="checkbox">
               <input type="checkbox"> Check me out
               </label>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group" >
               <input type="text" class="form-control" id="price" 
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
</form>
    </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Thanks for looking,  but it didn't seem to do it for me.  Tried playing around a bit but no good.